# Implementation of distributed greedy algorithm for finding maximum independent set

Tags: c++, graph-theory, distributed-computing, np-complete, distributed-algorithm

Can anyone share any implementation on how to implement a distributed greedy algorithm for maximum independent set or any implementation of distributed graph algorithm in C++? I checked this one https://github.com/arjun-menon/Distributed-Graph-Algorithms but unable to compile the code.

I tried compiling the code https://github.com/arjun-menon/Distributed-Graph-Algorithms but this does not work. I get the following error.[image]

Comment: Can you suggest any example which I can follow?

Comment: In C++ I meant, if there is any

Comment: Google is an excellent tool to find code samples.